# What exactly is a local expansion?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology, power-series, laurent-series

From time to time, I come across authors writing about performing a *local expansion* of a complex function $f$ at some point. This usually means performing a singular expansion (such as Laurent or Puiseux) or something more subtler – e.g., performing a singular expansion for one argument of a multivariate analytic function.

I have wondered if this term indeed means the same as "singular expansion" or possibly arbitrary "series expansion". I have not been able to find *any* text, in which the notion of *local expansion* is actually defined: it just usually strikes as bolt out of the blue. And in fact, I just cannot see any motivation for such term, as (at least in my understanding) almost all series expansions, possibly except some with infinite radius of convergence, are inherently valid only locally.

For these reasons, I would like to ask what exactly is meant by a *local expansion* and in case it is a synonym of some other term, what is the usual motivation of using this term instead of the other one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Defining things locally is an extremely useful and ubiquitous modus operandi in modern mathematics. A function having what you call a 'local expansion' is one example. This appears in the definition of an *analytic function*:

> an analytic function is a function that is locally given by a convergent power series 
>   **(Wikipedia)**

This means that although the function itself may not be given by a convergent power series, we can always find a small set around every point in its domain such that it is equal to a convergent power series when restricted to this set.

I think you might call this a 'local expansion'.

Comment: Well, this is what I meant by series expansions being inherently valid only locally. I think that I understand this, but my question was geared more towards the actual *use* of the term "local expansion" in literature. Is it a synonym of "series expansion", or "singular expansion", or...? And if so, what is the motivation behind using the term "local expansion" instead of the other one?

Comment: A 'local expansion' would be a particular expansion of an analytic function as a convergent power series around a point. An analytic function may have different power series expansions around each point, so it doesn't make sense to talk about the expansion of a function unless you qualify with 'local'.

Comment: I guess it makes sense to speak simply about the "series/singular/Taylor/Laurent/Puiseux/... expansion *at z = whatever*" without explicitly qualifying the expansion as local. Actually, this seems to be the usual practice and the term "local expansion" seems to be used only very rarely. In fact, I have never seen this term used in connection with Taylor series, but only in connection with singular expansions. Once again, I do not ask what the term could mean (I can guess that), but I would like to know more about the nuances with regard to its typical use in literature.

Comment: I think you now know why the word 'local' is used. I'm not sure what else you would like to know

Comment: @JáraCimrman You are actually implicitly qualifying that the expansion is local. A Taylor series for example, only agrees with the function in a neighbourhood of the point z = a - in other words, 'locally'.